# New Firebase auth API won't login my twitter users

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My app was authenticating users fine before, and then I implemented the new auth code for twitter:

```
    vc.twitterLogin = { session, error in
        if let session = session {
            let credential = FIRTwitterAuthProvider.credentialWithToken(session.authToken, secret: session.authTokenSecret)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { [unowned self] user, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.userInfo["NSUnderlyingError"])
                }
                if user != nil {
                    self.navCtrl.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                    self.delegate?.didAuthenticate(self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The twitter authentication works fine as you can see it's executing the FIRAuth block. Any ideas?

Here is the error:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={type = immutable dict, count = 3,
>   entries =>
>       0 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "Fail to get successful verify_credentials response from Twitter: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}"}
>       1 : errors = {type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : {type = immutable dict, count = 3,
>   entries =>
>       0 : reason = invalid
>       1 : message = {contents = "Fail to get successful verify_credentials response from Twitter: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}"}
>       2 : domain = global
>   }
>
> )}
>       2 : code = {value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
>   }
>   })

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to update your **Firebase Twitter API keys** in the new interface (Auth -> Sign In Method -> Twitter) to the auto-generated ones that Fabric.io has provided you with. These are available in the Fabric.IO interface.

My guess is that you've let Fabric.IO automatically generate new keys for you against the Twitter API and are using those in the new custom Fabric.IO entry in your Info.plist but have not yet changed them on Firebase. Updating these entries fixed the issue for me.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You were right, it's weird that Fabric doesn't update the keys on apps.twitter.com.

Comment: Excellent! Everyone should use API keys from Info.plist not from apps.twitter.com.

Comment: @DanielQ - What keys are you referring to? There's no secret key in the plist AFAIK?

Comment: @Robert - Now, I haven't access to my client Twitter account, but in code I have: Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey(Config.twitterKey, consumerSecret: Config.twitterSecret) -  twitterKey and twitterSecret are the same as in Firebase console. So, try to put Consumer Key (API Key) and  Consumer Secret (API Secret) there and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Worked it out. Ended up using the solution here instad of the Twitter SDK: https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample